# How to check if sqlite database disk image is malformed

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have an application which uses sqlite database for storage. Sometimes due to abrupt shutdown  the data base file gets corrupted and next time when i try to read i will get "database disk image is malformed" exception. i would like to know is there way in which i can programmatically check if the database file is corrupted corrupted or not.

Note: I have tried with the command `pragma integrity_check` but it returns "ok" for me even though the file was corrupted.

I am using the SQLite data adapters from [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient/)

Comment: What would be wrong with a try / catch block?

Comment: @Jonathan that will suffice, but i want to check the file even before making any query at the application start time.

Comment: SQLite's rollback journal will revert incomplete changes. What kind of (storage) device are you using that corrupts other data?